# How can I solely and properly decode a JWT using Tymon package?

Tags: php, laravel, debugging, jwt

I'm trying to use https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth so that I can grab the JWT, that's coming from the header, to decode and grab the payload that contains (name, email, etc).

I need to use the `RS256` algorithm to encode and decode.  What'll happen is exactly what'll happen if you post the long JWT here https://jwt.io/

Since I need to use the aforementioned algorithm, I need to use a `JWT_PUBLIC_KEY`, `JWT_PRIVATE_KEY` and optionally, `JWT_PASSPHRASE` based on the comment found in `config/jwt.php`.

In my code, I'm getting an error that says `Token Signature could not be verified`.  I've verified that public, private and passphrase are all set and that the header is showing a correct JWT but for some reason, I just can't get passed this error.

All I want to do is decode the long JWT token that's coming in the header.  I've ran out of options on what to do.

Anyone have any clue on how I can achieve this using the Tymon package?

This little snippet:

```
$token = JWTAuth::parseToken($request->header('authorization'));
// $payload = $token->getPayload();
dd($token);
```

dumps this below.  as you can see, everything is setup the way it should be.

```
Tymon\JWTAuth\JWTAuth {#326 // app/Http/Controllers/API/PermissionsController.php:14
  #manager: Tymon\JWTAuth\Manager {#296
    #provider: Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWT\Lcobucci {#297
      #secret: "mykey"
      #keys: array:3 [
        "public" => "filepath/public.pem"
        "private" => "filepath/private.pem"
        "passphrase" => "mypass"
      ]
}
```

This is my code attempting below to grab payload

```
$token = JWTAuth::parseToken($request->header('authorization'));
$payload = $token->getPayload();
dd($payload); // Error is thrown that says: Token Signature could not be verified.
$data = $payload->toArray();
return response()->json($data);
```

Comment: Did the JWT signed by the private key configured ?

Comment: @svgta yes, it's in the `storage` directory.

Comment: @svgta I used this as a guide https://medium.com/swlh/build-jwt-authentication-between-multiple-api-with-laravel-fbd03352aaa3

Comment: You don't have error when generating the JWT with the private key in RS256 ? Did you try in HS256 (with the secret) ?

Comment: And, on jwt.io did you try to put the JWT and the public key to verify it's ok ?